# Webhook for Azure SQL

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database, webhooks

Is there a webhook for Azure SQL, through which I can callback a URL when data is inserted into a table or some tables. I have searched online, but all I found was about settings alerts on Azure SQL performance. I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Azure SQL does not support this capability. However, you can create an Azure Logic App with a SQL trigger when rows are inserted in a table. Find detailed implementation steps at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-sqlazure.

Comment: Its just a polling trigger, which is same as having a timer trigger in webhook and checking if a new row was added.